# pChart - language issue

Tags: php, charts, pchart

I'm using pChart. My website has English & other language contents. I can able to print & view those all languages in the same page where chart is displayed. But inside the the chart     (i.e generated .png) part of content is not displayed. please see the below image. I have printed a array in the page. it got displayed. but in the top right, you can find few content not clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems font you are using not accept characters you wanna to print.
Try to use different font.